# web scraping for mobile apps

Tags: parsing, web-scraping, mobile, ios7

I have a question regarding web scraping/web parsing with mobile applications (an iOS 7 app as of now...). For example, I want to have images from various websites retrieved and aggregated to a device based on user inputs/preferences. I want the user to be able to select and store those images on the device with offline viewing capabilities as well. I have heard that using jQuery and JSON for parsing and programming through the server-side rather then the front-end is supposed to be more efficient...correct? 
What type/s of algorithms/code that I should use for performing website parsing and aggregating content into a mobile app? I apologize for being quite broad, I am in the early development stages. Thanks.

Comment: Your application is going to have at least two components. Firstly, an application that performs the scraping, which should will likely be entirely decoupled from your mobile application, and secondly, the iOS7 application itself. I would suggest you take a step back, think more about the overall architecture, and then come back with more specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a hybrid mobile app using Cordova/PhoneGap using just HTML/JavaScript/CSS and do an `XMLHttpRequest` or use jQuery's `$.ajax` to get the data from the website and parse it with jQuery selectors.

I would however recommend you do the web scraping in a service, so that if anything changes on the website you're scraping, you'll only have to update the service.